# How to add a unity app to a wix site?

Tags: deployment, unity-game-engine

I developed a simple app in Unity for a web site. How can I add my app to my wix site?
I tried finding on the web articles on how to do so but found nothing useful.

Comment: Does Wix not support .unity3d uploads? In that case you could perhaps host it externally and only embed the necessary HTML?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't follow..

Comment: You developed an app in Unity. So after a build you have some HTML and the .unity3d file, right? So what is the problem you're facing now?

Comment: I know how to add my HTML file to my web page, but how do I Upload the .unity3d file to the site?

Comment: Reading through some of the Wix documentation it seems they do not support such file uploads. So you'd have to host the .unity3d file somewhere else. Either on your own server, or on a dropbox or something like that.

Comment: how do I do this using dropbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A web build will provide you with an HTML and a .unity3d file. If your host allows you to embed HTML, take the relevant sections out of the HTML file and upload your .unity3d file.

If your host does not allow you to upload the required .unity3d file, you'll have to host it yourself. This can be on your own server, on a Dropbox, or wherever you find appropriate. This does require a small change in the generated JavaScript.

Inside your HTML file you'll find a line like

```js
u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "myAwesomeGame.unity3d");
```

Of course the exact name depends on however your build was named. If you don't host it in the same location as the HTML, you'll need to update this.

Say you're uploading it to your public Dropbox folder. In that case you can get a public link for the Unity3D file. Replace the call above with something like

```js
u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/XXXXXXXX/myAwesomeGame.unity3d");
```

and you should be good to go. Of course the same works for other hosts.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it didn't work. All I see are the get unity web player buttons and not the game I wrote on unity. I did exactly what you wrote above...

Comment: Could you link to the site?

Comment: I'm missing the required javascript when looking at your page's source. Am I overlooking it? Or did you only copy the HTML?

Comment: I added an embedded HTML and it's still doesn't run the game.

Comment: Ah, I see the frame's source now and it loads, but complains about a corrupt unity3d file. That's progress. :D The unity3d file seems rather small. An empty build I have here is larger than that. And when I try your link locally, I get the same error. So make sure that the build is correct and has the same size on Dropbox as on your local computer.

Comment: It worked - I copied the url wrong. Thanks a lot a lot!